# Initializing static field in interface with exception handling

Tags: java, interface, exception, static, field

Well, in fact I would like to do the following in an interface:

```
public interface ObjectMethods
{
    static Method getModulus = RSAPublicKey.class.getMethod("setModulus", byte[].class, short.class, short.class);
}
```

This of course leads to a compile error cause the exception thrown by this method call is not handled properly. But I cannot put a static block into an interface. I thought about building an Enum, but maybe someone where already faced to this problem. In fact it would not be a opportunity to put this static field into a class because I have to use interface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you HAVE to use an interface? This hardly sounds like a useful requirement... This is serious application code. Nothing to put into an interface anyway

Comment: @pvblivs When I "designed" my application/framework I decided to have inferfaces. It has its reason, but probably there would have been another way to implement the same functionality as I intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle this with a little bit of indirection.  (Code is untested.)

```
public interface ObjectMethods
    {
        public static class CONSTANTS
        {
               static final Method getModulus ;
               static
               {
                     try
                     {
                           getModulus = RSAPublicKey.class.getMethod("setModulus", byte[].class, short.class, short.class);
                     }
                     catch ( Exception cause ) { //handle it }
              }
         }

    }
```

Comment: Very interesting!! Thanks a lot. This looks like exactly what I wanna do.

Comment: Well at least there is still a little mistake either in my code or in yours. I got a compile error copying your code, because this static final field could not be initialized. Removing the `final` keyword (as expected) solve this "problem", but leads to the fleabite that you could override it...

Comment: @mozi Since I just posted my idea without compiling or testing it, there very well could be a compilation error in the posted code.

Comment: Of cource... just wrote the comment to avoid someone else maybe just c&p and wondering.

Answer (score 4):

Could you create a static helper class that wraps the logic with a try/catch block that swallows the exception?

```
public static class ObjectMethodHelper
{
    public static Method getModulusMethod() {
        try {
            return RSAPublicKey.class.getMethod("setModulus", byte[].class, short.class, short.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public interface ObjectMethods
{
    static Method getModulus = ObjectMethodHelper.getModulusMethod();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your afforts, but I think I do prefer emory's approach. =)

Comment: How would assign Method getModulus = ObjectMethodHelper.getModulusMethod(); where the return type  of public static void getModulusMethod() is void.